# Graph API Search: Not matching results are returned

Tags: facebook-graph-api, search

The Facebook post search keeps returning very strange results and everytime I try to find out rules it gets more confusing. I'm not even talking about operators and boolean logic like AND/OR.

E.g. try to search for the term "orange". My results all included "orang", but none the term I originally looked for: "orange".

Does anyone have an idea what may be the reason for this?